# How to store oAuth access token in variable

Tags: php, json, oauth-2.0, http-authentication

I have made successful oAuth request to server and now I want to extract response data from an http header response and I have write following code for it

```
$request_uri = "hostname?grant_type=[grant_type]=&client_id=[client_id]&client_secret=[client_secret]&code=[code]";

$resp = header("Location:".$request_uri)

$return_data = json_decode($resp, true);
```

but when i run the script the page redirected obviously redirected to the host name where i find json respond you can [see here](http://pastebin.com/MfdzvfW9)

THANKS,
GAUTAM

Comment: PHP's `header` function doesn't return anything - it's a void function. Maybe you want cURL?

Comment: @matthewh Thank you for your help. I'm just lost but you show me right direction..

THANKS,
GAUTAM